# Copying and sending data from receipt printer

Tags: networking, printer

Let's say I have a typical restaurant setting. 
A customer places an order (from the menu)
and an employee (server/cashier) enters the order
into a point-of-sale (POS) system. 
The system receives the order, calculates the price, tax and total price and prints a receipt (showing cashier name, time/date, order, price and so on). 
The receipt printer is an Epson Mobilink P80 Plus,
or similar printer with Wi-Fi capability.

I want to send (i.e., forward/relay) the receipt data
(cashier name, time/date, order, price, etc.)
to another computer (network-accessible) without touching the POS computer. 
Is this possible?  How can I do this?

I'm thinking that the printer has a buffer to store print instructions. 
Is it possible to copy these print data (from the buffer) to another computer? 
Here's a diagram of the scenario I envisage:

[image: diagram]

Comment: Can you explain exactly a scenario you'd envisage your process?

Comment: Alright, sorry if it wasn't clear. In a restaurant environment, the cashier would input customer's order into a POS system which it would be printed in form of receipt (order, price, tax and total price), would I able to forward that inputted data (in any legible form) to another computer in my house, in different network using only printer? Modified printer because in this scenario I can't touch the POS system.

Comment: We'll need to know how the data is generated and how the connection is established to the POS system. The model of the printer will also matter. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm not too knowledgeable on this subject. Edited the question.

Comment: I presume that the OP can *configure* the POS system to specify what printer to use, but he cannot modify the POS software, and wants to use the printer interface to tap into the system. I believe the OP has an XY problem. The real question is “How can I get data out of a closed system that has no external interface other than a printer interface?”, but he’s asking “How can I extract data from this printer?”

Comment: I believe the OP wants/needs something like the following: either (1) a computer that acts like a man-in-the-middle, that would (a) present an interface to the POS computer that looks like a printer, (b) accept print data from it, (c) print the data, and then (d) relay them to the other computer. Or (2) a “fake” printer driver, like a “Save as PDF” or “Send to OneNote” driver, to the same end.

Comment: Yes, sorry. what @Scott said is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need internet connectivity for this, but a network connection (e.g. WiFi) is essential.

I'm assuming both machines run Windows. If not, the following does not necessarily apply.

You start by making sure both PCs are on the network. On the PC that is connected to the printer, go to Printer Properties and click the Sharing tab. Make sure the printer is shared, and give it a share name. Unless both PCs run the same version of Windows, click the Additional Drivers button, and install the driver for the Windows version of the POS. Click OK. Click the Sharing tab and make sure that Everyone has at least Print permission. Unless there is a reason not to, I prefer to also give Manage Printer permission.

Now go to the POS and install a printer by browsing to the other PC. It should install cleanly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I couldn't touch POS computer? Is it possible using modified receipt printer?

Comment: If you cannot change anything on the POS computer, then there is no way it can connect to the other computer or the printer. Even if you change things on the printer (e.g. connect it directly to the network, instead of via a PC), you would not be able to tell the POS how to find the printer on the network.